# How to test if ASP.NET MVC 3.0 is installed on host machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I do not have access to physical machine.  How do know if ASP.NET MVC 3.0 is installed on shared hosting environment?

Comment: contact the system administrator and ask :)

Comment: @Herter Young grasshopper, the path to knowledge requires the understanding of what is, and what is not, an answer.

Comment: @Will May I mature into an adult grasshopper under your wings.. :P. My foolish youthful error will not be repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know this unless you try to deploy a sample MVC 3 application and test it for yourself (it will either crash or work and you will be fixed once and for all) or just ask the site administrator. Otherwise it would be pretty fun : we could know whether there's ASP.NET MVC 3 installed on google.com for example :-)